# How do I properly optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to optimize the following query. I've used EXPLAIN to troubleshoot but it keeps showing up in our logs as a non-indexed query. What am I missing? I've created indexes on all columns referenced, but it's still showing up.

```
select `users`.`nickname`, `users`.`userId`, `userdata`.`avatarUpdatedAt` 
from `users` 
inner join `userdata` on `userdata`.`userId` = `users`.`userId` 
order by `lastActivity` desc 
limit 28
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | SIMPLE | users | index | PRIMARY,userId | lastActivity | 8 | NULL | 28 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | userdata | eq_ref | userdata_userid_unique | userdata_userid_unique | 8 | prod.users.userId | 1 | Using index condition |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

```
# Time: 200703  6:14:18
# User@Host: prod[prod] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 17988  Schema: prod  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000201  Lock_time: 0.000011  Rows_sent: 28  Rows_examined: 56
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 1039
# Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
```

Comment: You dont have a "where" condition, it wont help you if you index columns.

Comment: the query is taking .0002 seconds and you are bothered by it?  sounds like you need to stop looking for non-indexed queries in your log.  some queries don't need indexes.

Comment: There are some incorrect answers here about indexes no being used for joins. Not true. But I suspect that your table/limit is so tiny (28 rows?) that the query optimiser has worked out it is quicker to just scan the table. Ad some other conditions, or a lot more rows and you would probably find different.

Comment: It _did_ use `INDEX(lastActivity)`, but not for the non-existent `WHERE` clause.  It used it for the `ORDER BY`.  It _did_ use an index for the other table.  Furthermore, the slowlog shows that it touched only 28 rows in each table; it is hard to beat that when you have `LIMIT 28`!  Bottom line, the "non-indexed query" complaint is lame.  (It's not the only one.)  And "created indexes on all columns" is probably hurting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a big table which contains millions of row, it would be the best to have `where` condition to filter out the data to make query run faster.

Indexing will help in retrieving data so just having index does not make query to run faster.

```
select 
    u.nickname, 
    u.userId, 
    ud.avatarUpdatedAt 
from users u
inner join userdata ud
on ud.userId = u.userId
where ud.avatarUpdatedAt >= '2020-01-01'
and ud.avatarUpdatedAt <= '2020-05-01'
order by lastActivity desc
```